# Join Multiple Columns Below Each Other From Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe df having columns 'a' and 'b' as shown:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 |
| NaN | 5 |
| 20 | NaN |
| 30 | 6 |

I want to make a new dataframe with a column 'c' having values of column 'a' and 'b' below each other with no NaN values as shown:

| c |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = df.unstack().dropna().astype(int).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('c')
print (df1)
    c
0  10
1  20
2  30
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(value_name='c')[['c']].dropna().astype(int)
df1 = df.melt(value_name='c').drop('variable',1).dropna().astype(int)
print (df1)
    c
0  10
2  20
3  30
4   4
5   5
7   6
```